# Calculate the SUM of presence per week

Tags: mysql, group-by

**where I come from:**

I have the tables 'event', user and user_event. Table event stores datetimes for start and end of an event. User_event holds information in which event a user is attending. Now it is easy possible to calculate the SUM of time a certain user is scheduled in events by just adding up all event durations.

But I need something different. Assuming that it is monday and user A is attending an event from 9-10am and from 2-3pm. The sum of these events is 2hrs. But I want to calulate how long the presence of a user is to take part in these events. In my example this is 6hr (from 9am - 3pm). I achieved this for one day (with time difference of max(event) and min(event) for the user and a given day.

**Where I wanna go:**

But I can´t find a solution for the task to sum the presence for the whole week. I need to add up all presence-sums for each day. But I cannot use the solution given for one day because min() and max() will only give me unique min and max values for the whole week and not for each day of the week.

Hope I described it well enough.

Thanks!

Comment: So you already have a query for the duration in a day – then you could construct an outer query around that that GROUPs the data the inner query gives by week and SUMs up the values over that group.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a `GROUP BY` on the days first, then on the week:

```
select 
    sum(d.dayFinish - d.dayStart) as weeklyPresence, 
    week(d.day) as weekNumber
    d.userId
from (
    select 
         to_date(e.startDate) as day, 
         min(e.startDate) as dayStart
         max(e.finishDate) as dayFinish,
         e.userId
    from events e
    group by to_date(e.startDate), e.userId
) d
group by week(d.day), d.userId
```

(I did not follow the actual syntax, some type conversions may be needed).

I suppose you have an `Events` table with `startDate` and `endDate` columns, and a `userId` foreign key that refers to the `user`.

The `to_date()` function rounds to the day (we group on that first), and the `week()` function determines the week (that's our second grouping).